# Xpath in Nightwatch.js

Tags: css, xpath, nightwatch.js

I have this structure

```
<div class ="wg-block">
  ...
    <h4 class ="number" >
       "Text"
```

I have to make sure that the element h4 with text "text" is in div.
I try this:

```
 .useXpath()
 .waitForElementVisible('/div[contains(@class, "wg-block")]/h4[text()="Text"]',1000)
```

but have an error.
How can I correctly be sure in visibility of this element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replace

```
'/div[contains(@class, "wg-block")]/h4[text()="Text"]'
```

with

```
'//div[@class = "wg-block"]//h4[normalize-space(text())="Text"]'
```

Note that starting `/` applicable for `root` element (which is `html`, but not `div`) and also `/` means direct child. So `/div/h4` means `h4` which is the direct child of a `root` element `div`.

You should use `//div//h4` to match `h4` which is descendant of `div` that is located somewhere in `DOM`

`text()="Text"` could be applied to match element `<h4>Text</h4>`, 
but if you want to match

```
<h4>
    Text
</h4>
```

you need to get rid of spaces and new line characters. In this case you can use `normalize-space(text())` method or `contains(text(), "Text")`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I have another problem, it is works, but only for text before space: "Text text_after_space".  I try sure in visibility text after space. How can I reach this problem, have you got any ideas? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: '//h4[text()[contains(.,"text_after_space")]]' It is work.