# night watch how to set a value for location details field

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, nightwatch.js

I am testing web app it was developed using react js with redux. I am testing that tool using night watch with automation. I want some clarification on below points.

1. How to set the value for date picker in night watch?
2. How to set the value for location entering details field(Ex:-when i am entering location details in google maps related location details it is coming i have to select one of them how to select the values)?
3. How to set the value for the drop down list but in our web app they are using menu list how to set that?
4. How to use xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:
 1. To setValue for the datePicker you can use simply click on datePicker and again click on the calander which is poping up whlie clicking on the datePicker. While doing this you should waitForElementVisible('#calander', 4000) where #calander is the selector for the calander.
 1.1 Or you can use SetValue directly on the date picker. like click #datePicker (use selector for finding the element on the page) and do setValue('#datePicker', '23.07.2018').

2. Again you can make use of setValue method in which takes two parametes which are selector and value setValue('#sourceLocation','#destinationLocaiton')
3. To choose value from the dropDown you can do something like this:

   browser.element('css selector' '.yourClassName .react-select-box-options .sectionOptions a.react-select-box-option',function(result)

   {
       var j = 1;
       for(var i = 1 ; i<=result.value.length; i++)

   {
       browser.click('#yourElementSelector')
       browser.getText('.yourClassName .react-select-box-options .sectionOptions a.react-select-box-option':nth-child(' + i + ')',function(text){

   if(text == "yourDesieredText"){
       //test your functionality
       }
       })
       }
       })
4. To locate the elements on the UI we use selector, or Xpath to use Xpath you can make use of the answer of the following question.

> [Xpath in Nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697261/xpath-in-nightwatch-js)